# Some accounts in instagram API are not working properly with realtime

Tags: callback, real-time, instagram, instagram-api

I believe this to be a bug and hopefully someone from facebook or instagram can confirm.

I am working with the real-time API from Instagram. I have one subscription which is working fine and my callbacks are working as intended.  Images are been projected as they should.

The problem is that not all of the accounts work. For example i got an account xxx1 and xxx2 that take a picture and use the tag 'somethingnew', I am subscribed to this tag, they take a picture and it is not projected. In fact the callback url is not even getting information. Then I use an account xxx3 which I just created and everything works as it should; in real time. Since I query from last tag taken I get the pictures that account xxx1 and xxx2 took.

Any ideas? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

First check your subscription are taken into account using the following API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions?client_secret=xxx&client_id=xxx
```

Note that it's a common problem to get an error on subscription. There are plenty of AWS servers answering to that API and some are not working. Ping api.instagram.com and you'll see you get multiple and different IP for that domain name. There is a DNS round robin and you are not reaching the same server every time.

I've found one server (IP) which seems to be working for subscription and have configured my server to use that one (by editing the /etc/hosts file). Not a reliable solution ... but it's working.

Then, note also that "real time" is not really "real time". You could receive a callback request for a picture posted several minutes (and sometimes a couple of hours) ago. That's weird ... but we've to live with that.

I've already open tickets for all these problems but got no answer from Instagram.

Comment: Any updates on this? Can the callback still be delayed by several minutes or even hours?

Comment: Personally, I do not use subscription method anymore as it's not reliable enough.

Comment: Is that because of the possible delays or what were the problems you encounter? How are you solving this challenge now?

Comment: Because of the delay, because some servers are not answering for that API, because it's really not reliable for production.

Comment: Now we have our own app (accepted by Instagram), we use the oauth to authentify the users and use the tag recent media api
`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: Thanks for response. In my case, it's crucial to get a callback as soon as the new image is posted so that won't work. :/